# How to get update parameters in the Active Record model's callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, callback

Is it possible to get a parameter list, which has been *assigned/updated*?

I want to get not the list of changed attributes from `before_save` callback, but the list of attributes which has been assigned by any means (direct assignment then save or by the `update_attributes` method).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

for example:

```
p = Person.new( name: 'Bob')
p.update_attributes( {:name, 'Bob'} )
```

and in the callback after the `update_attributes`:

```
name_changed? # return false
```

I want to get a list of assigned attributes like:

```
attr_assigned # returns something like {:name => 'Bob'} or so
```

**UPDATE 2:**

here's live session of my model

```
wl = WhiteLabel.last
wl.footer_text # "dfgdfgdfgdf"
wl.footer_text = "dfgdfgdfgdf"
wl.save

147: def on_subscription_update
148:    return if !valid? || back
149: 
=> 150:     binding.pry
151: 
152:    filter_out_postponed_attributes
153:    create_new_card_from_token      if stripe_card_token.present?
154:    update_subscription                 if user.stripe_customer_id && (subscription_type_id_changed? || !subscription_token)
155:    session_store = nil if last_step?
156: end

changed # []
changes # {}
```

I tried `wl.update_attributes({ :footer_text => "dfgdfgdfgdf"} )` also. The same result

Am I missing something from the docs?

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked. The method `#changed` provides you exactly the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The features provided by the [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) module get you access to the changed attributes.

```
record.changes        # => {"name" => ["Bill", "Bob"]}
```

You can also test a single attribute

```
record.name = 'Bob'
record.changed?       # => true
record.name_changed?  # => true
record.name_changed?(from: "Uncle Bob", to: "Bob") # => true
record.name_was       # => "Uncle Bob"
record.name_change    # => ["Uncle Bob", "Bob"]
record.name = 'Bill'
record.name_change    # => ["Uncle Bob", "Bill"]
```

Comment: Thank you, Simone! But I'm seeking for the feature that allows me to do such:

Comment: I added some example in my question

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked. The method `#changed` provides you exactly the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you do update_attributes it commits your requested changes into database so changes array became empty. If you want to track changes in this case use before save callback it will tell you all changes.

Comment: Thank you! I actually trying to track changes in before_save callback. What exact methods do you refer to?

Comment: If you just want to check if any field changed then use changed function it will return array. If you want values then use changes it returns hash with value changes from to to.